# How to perform Jet jobs by joining another node?

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-jet

Hi I have an issue with Hazelcast jet.

I have an app that initiates two nodes in `127.0.0.1:5701`, `127.0.0.1:5702` . When I run the application it creates DAG and am getting the required output. If I am trying to connect another instance of hazelcast jet say `127.0.0.1:5703` from another source (not from the app) the nodes are getting joined initially but throwing a serialization error like

> com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda to field com.hazelcast.jet.core.processor.SourceProcessors.

All the configuration has been set tcp-ip enabled so i can join both the nodes.

I also tried by starting the external node first and then app or vice versa, both produced the same error. I would like to know what is the right way to configure the external node for the jobs. Jet Version *0.6.1*

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's hard to say from your question and we'd need to see the code and classpaths. You might have a look here: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/jet/0.6.1/manual/#remember-that-a-jet-job-is-distributed

Comment: Which source are you using? It could be that the new node added doesn't have the same classpath as your other nodes?

Comment: thanks guys , I have not added the classes in the JobConfig and the reference point in the manual helped me alot.